# Convert different datetime formats to ISO 8601 format

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a lastUpdatedAt parameter that can contain the following datetime formats:

```
"lastUpdatedAt": "2017-09-09T01:30:42.560"
"lastUpdatedAt": "2019-07-26T13:51:08.000+0100",
"lastUpdatedAt": "2019-07-26T23:58:47+12:00",
"lastUpdatedAt": "2019-03-21T12:35:35Z",
```

my desired output would be the following format:

```
"lastUpdatedAt": "2019-07-21T12:47:44.000Z"
```

I have tried the following which of course doesn't apply to all formats:

```
<xsl:template match="string[@key='lastUpdatedAt']">
    <xsl:variable name="iso-dateTime" select="replace(. ,'^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})\s+(.*)([+-])(\d{2})(\d{2})','$3-$1-$2T$4$5$6:$7')" />
    <string key="lastUpdatedAt">
         <xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime($iso-dateTime), xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H'))"/>
    </string>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help on how could I transform these different datatime formats to my desired output?

Comment: For which of the four input formats does the direct approach of converting to `xs:dateTime` and using `adjust-dateTime-to-timezone` not work? Is that just the second format?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, for this one:```` "lastUpdatedAt": "2019-07-26T13:51:08.000+0100"```` I get an error that the Timezone hour must be two digits, but however also the rest is not really being transformed to UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to fix the potential lack of a timezone `:` separator with

```
adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime(replace(., '(\+|-)([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$', '$1$2:$3')), xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H'))
```

and then the results I get are `2017-09-09T01:30:42.56Z 2019-07-26T12:51:08Z 2019-07-26T11:58:47Z 2019-03-21T12:35:35Z`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifqp

So in the context of your template matching a single value you could use

```
<xsl:template match="string[@key='lastUpdatedAt']">
    <string key="lastUpdatedAt">
         <xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime(replace(., '(\+|-)([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$', '$1$2:$3')), xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H'))"/>
    </string>
</xsl:template>
```